# ArrayAdapter solo muestra un solo item de un ArrayList Dinamico Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, arraylist, arrayadapter

Tengo un problema con ArrayAdapter, no me visualiza dinamicamente los nuevo items creados. Con dinamicamente me refiero a que la creacion de los datos salen de un boton.
Estoy mandando mediante un boton "listo" de un dialogo personalizado,  un ArrayList de tipo objeto que tiene como nombre "Actividades", en donde contengo 6 variables.

Esto es lo que pido por pantalla basicamente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esa ArrayList la recibo en otra activity y la muestro con ArrayAdapter correctamente (hasta aqui todo bien) el problema esta en cuando quiero volver a mandar esos datos por el boton "listo" resulta que solo me muestra el item mas reciente, no me muestra los items ingresados anteriormente...

Es es el metodo donde capturo y mando los datos, esta en MainActivity, de aqui mando los datos en objeto ArrayList mediante Bundle:

```
public void guardar_datos(){
    id=id+1;
    nombre_actividad = nom_activi.getText().toString();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());
    Date date = new Date();
    fecha_actual= dateFormat.format(date);
    fecha_maximo = (a_max+"-"+m_max+"-"+d_max);
    hora_actual = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
    hora_max = (ho_max+":"+min_max);
    s_rango = Integer.toString(rango);

    ArrayList<Actividades> lista_activ = new ArrayList<Actividades>();
    //cada vez que se haga un registro de actividad mediante boton se van guardando los datos 
    lista_activ.add(new Actividades(id, nombre_actividad, fecha_actual, fecha_maximo, hora_actual, hora_max, rango));

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HoyActivity.class);

    Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable("clave", lista_activ);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Tengo esto en la activity 2, aqui recibo los datos y los muestro con adapter

```
public class HoyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView L_datos;
    private ArrayList<Actividades> lista_activ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hoy);
        
        L_datos = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mi_lista);

        Bundle objetoEnviado=getIntent().getExtras();
        ArrayList<Actividades> lista_tareas = null;

        if(objetoEnviado!=null){
            lista_tareas=(ArrayList<Actividades>) objetoEnviado.getSerializable("clave");

            ArrayAdapter<Actividades> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Actividades>(HoyActivity.this, R.layout.custom, lista_tareas);
            L_datos.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

**Cualquier aporte lo agradecería mucho, llevo días sin lograr nada**

Comment: Para clarificar aun mas mi problema, es que el ListView de pantalla me muestra un solo item sin importar cuantos items creo yo, algo como esto:

Mi ListView:
[1, Mi actividad, 2020-12-1, 16:05, 5].

Y lo que quiero que salga las veces que yo quiera registrar es:
[1, Mi actividad, 2020-12-1, 16:05, 5]. [2, Mi otra actividad, 2020-12-1, 16:05, 5]. [3, Mi otra actividad, 2020-12-1, 16:05, 5]. asi sucesivamente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que el problema está aquí (método guardar_datos):

```
 ArrayList<Actividades> lista_activ = new ArrayList<Actividades>();
//cada vez que se haga un registro de actividad mediante boton se van guardando los datos 
lista_activ.add(new Actividades(id, nombre_actividad, fecha_actual, fecha_maximo, hora_actual, hora_max, rango));
```

Si te fijas siempre creas un nuevo **ArrayList** y luego lanzas la **HoyActivity**. Deberías declarar el mismo fuera del método e inicializarlo en el **onCreate** de tu actividad para asegurarte de no tener una referencia nula.

Comment: Gracias, me diste la solucion amigo, no se por que no me fije en eso antes, gaste mas de 20 horas tratando de solucionar semejante tontada jajjaja.